# XSLT, how to copy a common node to a new location

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a bundle of xml object that all share a common node like following:

```
<rootElement1>
  <Header>
  ...
  </Header>
  ...
</rootElement1>

<rootElement2>
  <Header>
  ...
  </Header>
  ...
</rootElement2>
```

I'd like to have a single xslt transformation to copy just the "" to a new element. The result should look something like this:

```
<Wrapper>
  <Header>
  ...
  </Header>
  ...
</Wrapper>
```

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Wrapper>
    <xsl:copy-of select="rootElement1/tHeader" />
    ...
  </Wrapper>
</xsl:template>
```

However this way I need to write a different xslt transformation each time. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*However this way I need to write a different xslt transformation each time.*" Why? -- P.S. An XML document can have only one root element.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I guess he means writing a template for each `rootElement?` element with `?` € [1..k].

Comment: ^ what zx485 said

Comment: @David This makes no sense. There is only instance of `Header` in the requested output. And you said it's "a common node" - why would you want to repeat it?

Comment: What I meant is I have multiple xml objects each with different root elements but they all share a <Header> node. I wanted a single xslt transform that would pull out the <Header> node no matter what the root node was.

Comment: Well, it's kind of difficult to get that from your question. And you are misusing technical terms such as *root node* and *root element* (they are  not the same) - that's not helpful in a highly technical site such as this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Wrapper>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//Header" />
  </Wrapper>
</xsl:template>
```

This does copy all `Header` nodes in the whole XML file and wraps them in the `Wrapper` element.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!